# How to convert Celery async result into Json data?

Tags: python-3.x, celery, django-celery

In my Django application, I have defined a function with the celery @task filter.

```
   # tasks.py

   # import statements
   @app.task
   def categorise():
      # LOC
   return results # results should be returning json data
```

I am using .delay() method of Celery to invoke this function:

```
   def driver(self):
     results = categorise.delay()
     print("type of results: ", type(results))
     return results
```

The type returned in results variable is:

```
    type of results:  <class 'celery.result.AsyncResult'>
```

I am encountering the following error:

```
    Object of type 'AsyncResult' is not JSON serializable
```

In my Django settings.py file, I have added the following configurations but it is not helpful:

```
    # REDIS related settings
    REDIS_HOST = 'localhost'
    REDIS_PORT = '6379'
    BROKER_URL = 'redis://' + REDIS_HOST + ':' + REDIS_PORT + '/0'
    BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {'visibility_timeout': 3600}
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://' + REDIS_HOST + ':' + REDIS_PORT + '/0'
    CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
    CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

However I am not sure how the async result can be converted into json data.

### Update

Solution found.

Make use of .get() to retrieve the json output.

```
     def driver(self):
        results = categorise.apply_async()
        final_results = results.get()
        return final_results
```